# change csrf token after form submission in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, csrf

in my config file i have the following csrf setting:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

problem with that is after form submission the session doesn't get deleted.If the session doesn't get destroyed after form submission ,it will create a security risk.I mean that's how it should work that i submit a form and after form submission the token gets deleted from session.

How i can solve this issue?

Comment: *"i have the following csrf setting ... after form submission the session doesn't get deleted.If the session doesn't get destroyed after form submission ,it will create a security risk"* ~ I think you're confusing sessions with CSRF protection.

Comment: csrf tokens are put in a session , am i right  ?

Comment: I don't think so.  Referring to the CodeIgniter docs, there is nothing about CSRF protection in [the Session section](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), and nothing about sessions in [the Security section](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).  They are two different things.  After all, you can submit different forms unlimited times during a single user session.

Comment: CSRF protection is to ensure the form came from you. It is possible to have multiple active forms with the same CSRF value in them. If you change it after the first form returns then any outstanding form will fail when it returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!